# Not enough arguments to RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

Currently having the follow error in Firefox 64 where its giving this error which I have been searching online for a working fix but could not find one.

`TypeError: "Not enough arguments to RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription."`

Been using a few of the links to fix but to no avail and also the latter is outdated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCSessionDescription

[WebRTC Firefox: Not enough arguments to RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031933/webrtc-firefox-not-enough-arguments-to-rtcpeerconnection-setlocaldescription)

Chrome triggers another error which is `main.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` and this is when there's a if statement to check if the remotedescription.type matches offer

Would be grateful if anyone knows a fix.

```
 'use strict';

var configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }
  ]
};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

// Define action buttons.
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

/////////////////////////////////////////////

window.room = prompt('Enter room name:');

var socket = io.connect();

if (room !== '') {
  console.log('Message from client: Asking to join room ' + room);
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
}

socket.on('created', function(room) {
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  startVideo();
});

socket.on('full', function(room) {
  console.log('Message from client: Room ' + room + ' is full :^(');
});

socket.on('joined', function(room) {
  console.log('joined: ' + room);
  startVideo();
  callButton.disabled = true;
});

socket.on('log', function(array) {
  console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

async function sendMessage(message) {
  console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
  await socket.emit('message', message);
}

// This client receives a message
socket.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.sdp) {
    await pc
      .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), () => {
        if (pc.remotedescription.type === 'offer') {
          pc.setLocalDescription(pc.createAnswer())
            .then(function() {
              sendMessage({ sdp: pc.localDescription });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
            });
        } else {
          pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate)).catch(
            error => console.error(error)
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
});

pc.onicecandidate = event => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage({ candidate: event.candidate });
  }
};

pc.ontrack = event => {
  if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    console.log('Got remote stream');
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
const remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

// Set up initial action buttons status: disable call and hangup.
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;

// Add click event handlers for buttons.
callButton.addEventListener('click', callStart);
hangupButton.addEventListener('click', hangupCall);

function startVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    })
    .then(function(stream) {
      localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('getUserMedia() error: ' + err.name);
    });
  callButton.disabled = false;
}

async function callStart() {
  callButton.disabled = true;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;

  console.log('Sending offer to peer');
  await pc
    .setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer())
    .then(function() {
      sendMessage(pc.localDescription);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
    });
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function hangupCall() {
  pc.close();
  pc = null;
  callButton.disabled = false;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  console.log('Call Ended');
}
```

Comment: You're using both `await` and a success callback, mixing the promise version of this API with the legacy callback version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `pc.setRemoteDescription(desc, callback)` but do not provide an error callback, using a `.catch` instead. Firefox does not like using a callback without providing an error callback as well which leads to the "Not enough arguments" error.

Don't mix the deprecated callbacks with promises but instead use `pc.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(() => ...).catch(...)`

Comment: Not just Firefox, it's the spec. Chrome is too permissive here, leading to confusion.